# How do I zip files with the same name?

Tags: macos, compression, zip

I'm on a Mac OS X 10.10.4

I need this:

- Detecting files with the same name, but different extension. (aaa.ai, aaa.eps, aaa.pdf and bbb.ai, bbb,eps, bbb.pdf and so on)
- Compressing those with the same prefix into a .zip. In the end I would have aaa.ai, aaa.eps, aaa.pdf, aaa.zip and bbb.ai, bbb,eps, bbb.pdf, bbb.zip and so on.

Comment: At the moment I've found only an apple script the do this thing but only with 2 files with the same names. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4307961

Answer (score 0):

```
zip zipfile.zip aaa.*
```

Simple as that. `*` tells zip to look for anything that matches `aaa.` then accepts any extension.

Comment: The problem is also name of the files. I have aaa, bbb, ccc and so on

Comment: @Ivan you only specified aaa so I only answered for aaa